# Browsing Revisions in Custom Post Types takes me Empty Post Listing

Tags: revisions

I have created a custom theme and everything works fine except for the same erratic behaviour when I would like to browse the revisions of any of my content types (pages and posts revisions work fine).

I have enabled the revisions on the content types and they show fine. For instance, the **Browse** button for revisions for one of the content types post displays the following link (currently shows there are 5 revisions available)

http://localhost:8888/test_site/wp-admin/revision.php?revision=1582

When I click on it, it displays the **All Posts** admin listing:

[image]

I have disabled all plugins except for the 2 that I use (one is ACF and the other is my own plugin that defines the content types).

Other than defining revisions as part of the content type's features upon creation, I don't think there is another pre-req, so I am a bit baffled on why it does not display the revisions when the browse button is clicked - any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This had to do with the user not having the CPT capabilities access set up properly.

I was setting custom capabilities as such:

```
          'capabilities' => array(
            'publish_posts' => 'publish_' .$this->type,
            'edit_posts' => 'edit_' .$this->type,
            'edit_others_posts' => 'edit_others_' .$this->type,
            'edit_published_posts' => 'edit_published_' .$this->type,
            'delete_posts' => 'delete_' .$this->type,
            'delete_others_posts' => 'delete_others_' .$this->type,
            'read_private_posts' => 'read_private_' .$this->type,
            'edit_post' => 'edit_' .$this->type,
            'delete_post' => 'delete_' .$this->type,
            'read_post' => 'read_' .$this->type
        ),
```

In the code, ideally when the plugin is activate, I should've had a code that set the capability for the user I wanted (this is from the class I built, the options member has an array with the custom capabilities)

```
    $capabilities = $this->options['capabilities'];
    $admin_role = get_role( 'administrator' );
    $editor_role = get_role( 'editor' );
    foreach ( $capabilities as $capabilities => $capability_name ) {
        $admin_role->add_cap( $capability_name );
        // $editor_role->add_cap( $capability_name );
    }
```

Once I messed with these settings, the revisions worked as expected.